# Json data type dosen't work in schema Laravel 5.2

Tags: json, schema, laravel-5

**Laravel 5.2.42**
When i running this code in cmd `php artisan migrate` i got this error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'json not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' 
at line 1 (SQL: create table `checkouts` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment 
primary key, `user_id` int not null, `stuff` json not null) default character set utf8 
collate utf8_unicode_ci)
```

This is my **checkouts table migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCheckoutsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('checkouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->json('stuff');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('checkouts');
    }
}
```

Model **Checkout.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Checkout extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'checkouts';

    protected $casts = ['stuff' => 'json'];
}
```

How can i solve that issue? or there is another idea to create array data type in schema?

Comment: well, does your database support the type json?

Comment: Well what kind of database do you use? Do you have phpmyadmin available? Just open the db and check if you can select json as column type

Comment: Yes phpmyadmin, but i can't select json as column type

Comment: @AhmedSk - Your MySQL should be upgraded to the current 5.7 branch in order to use JSON. If you can't upgrade, then change it to a `text` column, and use accessors and mutators to encode and decode to and from JSON.

Comment: Agree - Laravel support JSON but that doesnt mean your database is able to use it. With Laravel you can use different Databases which support different types.

Comment: Oh, thanks guys i recommend `text` data type idea with use encode & decode